# Get distinct results with latest records

Tags: mysql

I have following `table` in my database.

[image]

I am trying to write a query which returns some rows from the above table.

The returning list:

1. Should not contain duplicates of `Currency2_Id`
2. If there are duplicates of `Currency2_Id` found, the latest record should be returned

   For an example in above table there are two records which has `Currency2_Id = 7`. The latest record from those two is the record which has `Date = 2012-12-28`. 
   So my final result should be something like this.

[image]

This is the query I tried.

```
SELECT Id, Currency1_Id, Rate, Currency2_Id, Date 
FROM currency_ex_rate_txn
GROUP BY Currency2_Id
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

But the resultset I get contains the record with `Currency2_Id = 7` and `Date = 2012-12-25` instead of the record with `Currency2_Id = 7` and `Date = 2012-12-28`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  c1.Id, 
  c1.Currency1_Id, 
  c1.Rate, 
  c1.Currency2_Id, 
  c1.`Date`
FROM currency_ex_rate_txn c1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Currency2_Id, MAX(`date`) LatestDate
    FROM currency_ex_rate_txn
    GROUP BY Currency2_Id
) c2  ON c1.Currency2_Id = c2.Currency2_Id
     AND c1.`date`       = c2.LatestDAte
ORDER BY c1.`Date` DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT Id, Currency1_Id, Rate, Currency2_Id, Date   
      FROM currency_ex_rate_txn c1 
             where Date = (select max(Date) from currency_ex_rate_txn c2 
                           where c2.Currency1_Id = c1.Currency1_Id);
```

BTW - it's not a great idea to use reserved words as column names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However this gives me all the records which are created on `max(Date)` ( ie.2012-12-28). I need the latest record only when `Currency2_Id` are the same. Special thanks for the tip about "reserved words".

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your problem 

`SELECT Id, Currency1_Id, Rate, Currency2_Id, DATE 
FROM currency_ex_rate_txn
WHERE Id IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM currency_ex_rate_txn GROUP BY Currency1_Id)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I need the latest record(by date).